TikZ pgfplot 3d graph number positioning
Can you see the x-axis ticks (r_{AB})? There are two lines: I would like to make sure that the numbers lie underneath in the line that goes downwards.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xtick={1,2,3,4},
            ytick={1,2,3,4},
            ztick={0,50,100,150,200,250},
            zmin=0,
            xlabel={$r_{\mathrm{AB}}$\hspace{3px}(Å)},
            ylabel={$r_{\mathrm{BC}}$\hspace{3px}(Å)},
            zlabel={Energia (\unit{\kilo\cal} \unit{\mol^{-1}})},
            tick align=outside,
        ]
            \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,domain=1:4.5,y domain=1:4.5] {(128*(1-exp(-(x-1.3)))^2)+(128*(1-exp(-(y-1.3)))^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


xticklabel style={xshift=7pt}
